# Exercise 1 of Section 2.1 in "Category Theory for Computing Science".

Tags: logic, category-theory, computer-science

I am trying to solve Exercise 1 of Section 2.1 in the book "Category theory for Computing Science" written by Michael Barr and Charles Wells.

The exercise is:

> Prove that sets (as objects) and injective functions (as arrows) form
> a category with functional composition as the composition operation c.

The solution attached to the end of this book is:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcLlP.png)

The definition of category in this book is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aSa4.png)

I cannot understand the solution in the book. In my understanding, to prove the existence of a category, we just need to satisfy the conditions C-1 to C-4.
The solution shows "the identity functions are injective and
that composite of injective functions is injective". As far as my understanding, the two properties do not belong to any one of C-1 to C-4.

I would be much appreciated if anyone could give me some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the solution is showing is that the composition of morphism (in your specific example the morphisms are injective functions between sets) is a morphism. That is to say that the composition is well defined. Lastly you need to check that the identity is itself a morphism. These are "hidden" conditions just like how in the definition of group $(G,*)$ one may omit that the operation $*$ is defined for every pair of elements in $G$ and is an in $G$. This is done by requiring that $*: G\times G \rightarrow F$. Similarly there are some other hidden conditions for something to be a category. Namely that compositions of morphism is itself a morphism and that the identity is a morphism.

Comment: Thank you most sincerely!